# Tweepy get reply

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I created a twitter bot using the Tweepy module in Python. I've been looking through the documentation for Tweepy and can not seem to find anything related to this. I just need to get the tweet id of tweets that reply on any of my tweets. I think maybe you could use API.search() but there are no parameters related to replies to your own tweet.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the api to get the most recent tweets from your account. Then, get your tweet ids. Then get tweets that tag you with `api.search(q='to:@yourhandle')`. Now, for each tweet you searched, you can see if it has the attribute `in_reply_to_status_id_str`. If it does, you can get the tweet id from there and match with your current tweets.